# nodejs typescript: the index.d.ts file is not generated inside the dist folder though declaration is set to true

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have multiple microservices project, all of them have the same **tsconfig.json** given below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowjs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
     },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratormetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest", "reflect-metadata"],
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "declaration": true
  },
 "exclude": ["node_modules, "dist", "coverage", "webpack"],
 "include": ["src", "tests"],
 "ts-node": {
   "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
 }
```

}

I have a **tsconfig.shared.json** given below

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/shared"]
}
```

build script in **package.json**

```
scripts: {
  "build": "rm -rf ./dist && rm -rf src/shared/dist && tsc --project tsconfig.shared.json && tsc-alias && mv ./dist ./src/shared"
}
```

I understood the difference between `--project` and `--build` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73126644/8370370)

When I run the build command locally on other working projects, I see the below in generated **dist** folder

```
dist
  --shared (folder)
    --lib
    --models
    --index.d.ts
    --index.js
    --index.js.map
  --index.d.ts <------------
  --index.js
  --index.js.map
```

The `index.d.ts` inside the dist folder pointed by the arrow above has exports of shared folder. **Ex:** `export * from './shared';`
When I run the build, I don't see `index.d.ts` and other index files inside **dist** folder. the `"declaration": true` in `tsconfig.json` is creating the `index.d.ts` inside **dist/shared folder**.

The exact same build command and this `tsconfig.json` of other proects generates `index.d.ts` inside **dist** folder without issues.

Due to this, when I publish and install this package in other projects/microservices. I get the error "cannot find module or its type declarations". (referred all posts online for this error msg)

This happens for the latest bumped version in `package.json` that has my changes. If I rollback to previous version, it works fine.

I could see the necessary index files inside **dist** folder on `npm run build` locally for the previous `package.json` versions, just my version bump has this issue, though its published, I don't see the index files inside **dist** folder in published artifact as well.

Not sure what went wrong, I didn't make any changes to config files, just bumped `package.json` version.

The version of typescript I'm using is 4.9.5 and I tried upgrading ts version.